# match until an unescaped version of a character

Tags: javascript, regex

Am processing a string format like `[enclosed str]outer str[enclosed str]`
and am trying to match all `[enclosed str]`.

The problem is that I want any character except an unescaped version of `]`(that is a `]` not preceded by a `\`) to be within the square brackets.

For instance

```
str = 'string[[enclosed1\\]]string[enclosed2]';

// match all [ followed by anything other ] then a ]
str.match(/\[[^\]]+]/g)
// returns ["[[enclosed1\]", "[enclosed2]"]
// ignores the `]` after `\\]`

// match word and non-word char enclosed by []
str.match(/\[[\w\W]+]/g)
// returns ["[[enclosed1\]]string[enclosed2]"]
// matches to the last ]
// making it less greedy with /\[[\w\W]+?]/g
// returns same result as /\[[^\]]+]/g
```

Is it possible within Javascript RegExp to achieve my desired result which is

```
["[[enclosed1\]]", "[enclosed2]"]
```

Comment: my problem is you set the regular expression mode to "advanced professional". and am not at that level yet!

Comment: What about using [`/\[+[^\[]+\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/i1REKm/2) ;).

Answer (score 1):

With regex in javascript not supporting a negative lookbehind this is the best I could come up with:

```
/(?:^|[^\\])(\[.*?[^\\]\])/g
```

group 1 will contain the string you want.

https://regex101.com/r/PmDcGH/3